# order() not behaving as expected

Tags: r

Ok. I am pretty convinced I am about to embarrass myself, but here we go.

I cannot get `order()` to work properly. I am trying to come up with a composite ranking by two different factors, which is distilled down to an example below:

```
test1 <- rnorm(5)
test2 <- abs(rnorm(5))
test1; test2
> 0.4839582  0.1665794 -0.7648058 -0.5492701  0.6616983
> 0.8491913 0.2840523 2.3413548 0.7299879 0.1584666
test1Ord <- order(test1, decreasing = TRUE)
test2Ord <- order(test2)
test3Ord <- test1Ord + test2Ord
test1Ord; test2Ord; test3Ord 
> 5 1 2 4 3
> 5 2 4 1 3
> 10  3  6  5  6
order(as.numeric(test3Ord), decreasing = TRUE)
> 1 3 5 4 2
```

As you can see, the vector c(10, 3, 6, 5, 6) should be ordered 1, 5, 3, 4, 2 or 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 (since the tie at 6). This is not what the output is.

Am I missing something?!

Comment: read `?order` : 1,3,5,4,2 means that the first element is the biggest, followed by the third element (the first 6) then by the fifth (the second 6), ... It DOESN'T mean that the first element is the biggest then that the second element is the third largest and so on.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I just got mixed up in my head, confusing rank and order. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @lukehawk looks like I was reading a little too quick and didn't answer your question correctly. I deleted it and you can answer yourself now if you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was looking for rank(). (I was previously unaware of this function.) I am pretty familiar with order(), but got mixed up in what I was trying to do.

The rank() of the vector provides what I was going for.

Thanks to all for setting me straight!